# Configure the external csv dictionary to clickhouse

Tags: sql, csv, clickhouse

I need help. I have csv file "names":

```sh
id, name, surname etc
1, John, Smith etc
2, Bob, Jackson etc
...
```

I want to configure the external csv dictionary to clickhouse to use data from csv in queries (I want to understand the connection principle). Now I have error "Error running query: Code: 62...". My code:

```xml
CREATE DICTIONARY names
(
    id UInt64,
    name String,
    surname String

)
PRIMARY KEY  id 
SOURCE(/C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\files\names.csv)
LIFETIME(0)
```

```sql
SELECT
dictGetOrDefault('names', 'name', number + 1, (number * 10)) AS val,
toTypeName(val) AS type
FROM names
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: *file/path* should point to *local*-path on the server not client-machine (see https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/dicts/external_dicts_dict_sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-local_file)

Comment: consider to use [CREATE DICTIONARY](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/create/#create-dictionary-query) instead of xml-configs - it is more convenient way

Comment: vladimir, I edited code. Could you watch?

Comment: *SOURCE* should point to server's path like *'/opt/dictionaries/os.tsv'* - you need to copy your csv-dict to server where CH is deployed (copy this file on each node of cluster), or access to this file through [HTTP](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/dicts/external_dicts_dict_sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-http). CH is hosted on Linux-machine, it does know nothing about any files on your local Windows-machine.

Comment: + you can load(insert) this file into CH mergTree table, use this table as a dictionary source